# Simple While Loop Example Explanation

Tags: java, methods

Assume that the method enigma has been defined as follows:

```
public int enigma(int n)
{
    int m;

    while (n >= 10) {
        m = 0;
        while (n > 10) {
            m += n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        n = m;
    }
    return (n);
}
```

What is the value of enigma(1995) ?
          I understood that the value of enigma(1995) is 3. What is the step by step?

Comment: is this homework? add the homework tag

Comment: not homework, just trying to figure it out

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about it?

Comment: What about the code is confusing you that prevents you from doing the step-by-step yourself?

Comment: The way I see it is that when n=1995, m+=5 and from there I do not know where to go.

Comment: did you try running it? or to add print statements to track advancement?

Comment: it seems this method has been written TO BE a puzzle.

Comment: It is a puzzle that I am trying to figure out how to solve.

Comment: Step through it with the debugger.

Comment: Have you tried debugging or adding `System.out.println()` at appropriate locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer while runs until `n` becomes less than 10.

The inner loop runs until `n` becomes less than or equal to 10, then we assign the value of `m` to `n`, so the outer loop can be evaluated again.

What happens in the inner loop?  `m` is incremented by the remainder of `n` divided by 10 (so 5 when `n==1995`), then `n` is set to be the (integer) result of the division (so now `n==199`).  This is repeated a few times:

```
n=1995 => m=5,n=f199
n=199  => m=5+9=14,n=19
n=19   => m=14+9=23,n=1
```

Since `n` is now not larger than 10, the inner loop ends and `n` is set to `m`(==23), then we do this again:

```
n=23 => m=3,n=2
```

Since `n` is now not larger than 10, the inner loop ends and `n` is set to `m`(==3).  Since now `n` is less than 10, the outer loop exist and we arrived to the result of `n`(==3).

Comment: ^ agreed. No fun anymore

Answer (score 3):

Well you clearly are well on your way, but I don't want to solve the whole thing for you, so I'll just give a nudge:

when the inner loop starts, `n = 1995` and `m = 0`.  As you've already figured out at the end of the loop, `n = 199`, `m = 5`.   the loop starts again from the top... `n = 199`, `m = 5`... etc

Answer (score 0):

Just use an eclipse (java) installation, make a static main method and call your function.

When you use the debugger, you could do anything step by step and watching the vars